# Reorder expression in descending negtive power of a variable using Sage or Sympy

Tags: python, sympy, sage

I have an expression

```py
1/24*(8*(l + 1)*l + 5*(2*E*(l + 1)*l + 3)/E - 6)/E
```

I want to reorder it to the form

```py
a * E**1 + b * E**0 + c * E**(-1) + d * E**(-2) + ...
```

`sympy.simplify()` gives me a close result.

```py
from sympy import simplify
simplify(1/24*(8*(l + 1)*l + 5*(2*E*(l + 1)*l + 3)/E - 6)/E)
```

output

```py
(6*E*l**2 + 6*E*l - 2*E + 5)/(8*E**2)
```

It didn't combine `8*E**2`.

What I expect is

```py
3/4*l**2*E**(-1) + 3/4*l*E**(-1) - 1/4*E**(-1) + 5/8*E**(-2)
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `expand` puts the terms in the order you wanted:

```py
>>> expand((6*E*l**2 + 6*E*l - 2*E + 5)/(8*E**2))
3*l**2/(4*E) + 3*l/(4*E) - 1/(4*E) + 5/(8*E**2)
```